# Tried using tailwindcss with express.js . The Output CSS files were generated but getting simple h1 heading instead of h1 of text-6xl and bg-slate

Tags: javascript, html, css, express

[package JSON file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edXOM.png)

[index.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQiW1.png)

[index EJS file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoIU9.png)

[file hierarchy used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfaCm.png)

[tailwind config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwxZt.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You're not closing the `link` tag in your index.ejs. Hence the `</head>` is red.

Comment: @Reyno Thank you It worked but i don't know how.I just converted .ejs file to .pug and totally removed the content option. inspired from https://github.com/catalinpit/nodejs-tailwind